# Provisioning Profile Disappeared From Xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I had a couple of provisioning profiles that disappeared from Xcode overnight. Neither my machine nor Xcode restarted. I was still able to create an archive the day before.

If I drag the .mobileprovision files into iTunes again, it says they already exist. They no longer show up under Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile. And I don't remember them ever being listed under Preferences -> Account.

I assume they expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my system date back and it re-appeared!